# Is there a way to convert a picture to CMYK using php or javascript (or any other language)?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, cmyk

I did quite some research in the last few days on this topic and didn't find an answer yet, which worked form me.
I need to convert the colors of an image (jpeg or in a pdf, doesn't matter since I can convert that quite easily) from RGB to CMYK. The process looks like this:

HTML5 Canvas (p5.js) -> Save Image (jpeg or png) -> Have a printable PDF (using jsPDF)

Somewhere in there should be a conversion to CMYK Colors.

The only option I found was to use Imagick/ImageMagick. But since I use a shared server at 1&1 I cant really install it. At this point the language doesn't really matter, I just want to get it done easily.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can embed RGB images in PDFs; the printing process should take care of CMYK conversion.

Comment: Or, well, the actual question I'm probably trying to ask here is "Why do you need a CMYK image?".

Comment: The printing company I am working with said they need CMYK Data preferably in a PDF. So from what I learned I need to embed a CMYK image into the PDF.

Comment: That *sounds* like standard printing specs if you're sending them an advert or similar (e.g. vector/text and bitmap images combined - which you'd export to PDF from InDesign or Quark) - however, if it's *really* just a picture (jpg/png) they should be able to work with that, CMYK or RGB.